# Laravel 5.1 has many through relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following tables setup:

```
User
    - id

Timesheet
    - id
    - user_id
```

Users also have roles.  A user can have an `employee` role or a `supervisor` role.  Users can be assigned to supervisors, so I have setup the following relationship on the `User` model:

```
/**
 * The supervisors that are assigned to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function supervisors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User', 'supervisor_user', 'user_id', 'supervisor_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The `supervisor_user` table is a pivot table and has data like so:

```
user_id    supervisor_id
1          5
```

The above means that the user with id of `1` is assigned to the supervisor with id of `5`.

**I now want to be able to get a list of `Timesheet`s that belong to `User` who are assigned to a `Supervisor`.**

I have tried setting up a relationship like so:

```
/**
 * Timesheets that belong to assigned users.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function supervisorTimesheets()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Timesheet\Timesheet', 'Costain\Models\User\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

However, this results in the following SQL query which does not join my `supervisor_user` table in order to only return timesheets that belong to users who are assigned to this supervisor:

```
select `timesheet`.*, `user`.`id` from `timesheet` inner join `user` on `user`.`id` = `timesheet`.`user_id` where `user`.`id` = 1
```

Does anyone know how I can return timesheets that belong to users who are assigned to a specific supervisor?

Comment: let me clarify, do you mean the query **does not join my `supervisor_user` table** as in you need to get supervisor information and it's timesheet? if so, you could simply, `Supervisor::with('supervisorTimesheet')->get()`. Reference, [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). another way around is define a chain of relations then query it like `Supervisor::with('supervised_user.user_timesheet')->get()`, this will certainly fetch supervisor, it's supervised user, and timesheet completely.

Comment: No, sorry if i'm not being clear.  I do not have a `Supervisor` model, only a `User` model, but a `User` can have a `Supervisor` role.  Do you need me to post the `Role` relationship?  All I want to do is be able to get a list of timesheets that belong to users who are assigned to a supervisor.  For example, if user id 1 has a supervisor role and is assigned to user id 5, when logging is an user id 1, I want to be able to see all timesheets that belong to user id 5.

Comment: ah i see, i was distracted by your `supervisor_user` table. also, take note that `hasManyThrough()` is a relation for 1-to-Many - to - 1-to-Many relations, a two layer 1-to-Many relation. as i read you also had a pivot table, i don't think `hasManyThrough()` can do it. what i can think of just like my second proposed query - which uses `.` to define *nesting* relations.

Comment: OK, I have tried `$user->with('supervisors.timesheets')->get()` but this results in the following output: http://pastebin.com/rHFApXJ3.  It does not return timesheets of users that are assigned to the supervisor.

Comment: uh, i had to make it clear, a supervisor (which also a user) had a relation to **supervised** user in `supervisors` relation? i thought it was the other way around (belongsToMany).. if you invoke `with('supervisors.timesheets')`, you're asking given user *supervisor's own timesheets* (not the user timesheet). perhaps a scratch on relation between user, supervisor, and timetable could help.

Comment: ps. what i want to say is, look at `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User', 'supervisor_user', 'user_id', 'supervisor_id')->withTimestamps();` especially the position of `user_id` and `supervisor_id`. this relation define that *this user is supervised by*. then, what we need is, it's inverse, *this user oversee these user*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasManyThrough` can only be used with `HasOne`/`HasMany` relationships. It cannot be used with a many to many (`BelongsToMany`) relationship.

I think what you're really looking for is a `whereHas()` query:

```
$supervisor = User::find(5);
$timesheets = Timesheet::whereHas('user.supervisors', function ($query) use ($supervisor) {
    $query->where('id', $supervisor->id);
})->get();
```